# Iteración sobre objeto (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucle-for, objeto

tengo que crear una función que reciba un arreglo de objetos como parámetro y un string. Deberá retornar un nuevo arreglo de objetos, teniendo como parámetro la propiedad que fue pasada como string.

EJEMPLO:  oneProperty(arreglo, “edad”) debe retornar [ { edad: 20 }, { edad: 22 } ]

El problema que tengo es que no encuentro la forma de acceder a la propiedad del objeto mediante un string

```
    function oneProperty(array, string) {
      let array2 = []
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      console.log(array[i].string)
       }
    };
```

Mi pregunta es como hacer para acceder a la propiedad de un objeto mediante una variable, en este caso la variable string

Answer (score 0):

puedes acceder a una propiedad tratándolo como arreglo. De la siguiente manera

```js
const obj = { edad: 10, sexo: 'M' };
console.log(obj['edad']);
```

Te quedaría algo como esto:

```js
function oneProperty(array, string) {
  let result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result.push({[string]: array[i][string]});
  }
  return result;
}

const arr = [
  { nombre: 'a', edad: 10 },
  { nombre: 'b', edad: 20 }
];

const edades = oneProperty(arr, 'edad');
console.log(edades);
```

Tambien lo puedes hacer con `map`:

```js
function oneProperty(array, string) {
  return array.map(item => ({[string]: item[string]}));
}

const arr = [
  { nombre: 'a', edad: 10 },
  { nombre: 'b', edad: 20 }
];

const edades = oneProperty(arr, 'edad');
console.log(edades);
```

Saludos.